# Error al crear Trigger en Postgresql - syntax error at or near "BEGIN"

Tags: postgresql, trigger, postgresql-9.3

Actualmente estoy intentando crear un trigger en `postgresql` para que me realice una inserción en una tabla. Pero al ejecutar la sentencia el resultado arroja:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BEGIN"
>   LINE 4: BEGIN

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_INS_DOCUMETTYPE
AFTER INSERT ON DOCUMENTTYPE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN   
INSERT INTO AUD_DOCUMENTTYPE (
DOCT_ID,
DOCT_NAME,
DOCT_REGISTERBY,
DOCT_REGISTERDATE,
DOCT_OPERATION
) VALUES (    
:NEW.DOCT_ID,
:NEW.DOCT_NAME,
:NEW.DOCT_REGISTERBY,
:NEW.DOCT_REGISTERDATE,
'INSERT'
);
END;
```

¿Qué tengo mal?

Comment: Esa sintaxis parece ser de Oracle. ¿De donde sacaste el código?

Comment: El codigo me guie por la siguiente publicación  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772192/postgresql-trigger-on-insert-or-update

Comment: La respuesta en ese hilo es para Oracle.

Comment: Como puedo hacer algo similar sin necesidad de crear una función?

Comment: que yo sepa, esto no esposible en PostgreSQL. Parece que necesitas crear una función primero al que luego ligas el trigger. Te puse un ejemplo en mi respuesta.

Comment: No es posible hacerlo en postgree sin hacer la función...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La sintaxis que tienes es para Oracle. Aunque no soy experto con los triggers en PostgreSQL, parece que debes definirlos diferentemente. Necesitas hacerlo en 2 etapas:

1. Crear una función que contiene la lógica.
2. Crear el trigger que llama la función.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo que debería funcionar correctamente en tu caso.

**Función:**

```
create function TRG_INS_DOCUMETTYPE_FUNCTION()
returns trigger as
$BODY$
BEGIN   
INSERT INTO AUD_DOCUMENTTYPE (
DOCT_ID,
DOCT_NAME,
DOCT_REGISTERBY,
DOCT_REGISTERDATE,
DOCT_OPERATION
) VALUES (    
NEW.DOCT_ID,
NEW.DOCT_NAME,
NEW.DOCT_REGISTERBY,
NEW.DOCT_REGISTERDATE,
'INSERT'
);

return new;

END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

**Trigger:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_INS_DOCUMETTYPE
AFTER INSERT ON DOCUMENTTYPE
FOR EACH ROW
execute procedure TRG_INS_DOCUMETTYPE_FUNCTION();
```

**[Demostración](http://rextester.com/DGMDK97439)**

Comment: +1 por ganarme en velocidad

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tenés que hacer es crear una función que se ejecutará en el trigger. Algo asi:

```
Create or replace function nombre_funcion() 
  RETURNS trigger 
  AS 
  $$
begin
INSERT INTO AUD_DOCUMENTTYPE (
DOCT_ID,
DOCT_NAME,
DOCT_REGISTERBY,
DOCT_REGISTERDATE,
DOCT_OPERATION
) VALUES (    
DOCT_ID,
DOCT_NAME,
DOCT_REGISTERBY,
DOCT_REGISTERDATE,
'INSERT'
);

RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Después creas el trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_INS_DOCUMETTYPE
AFTER INSERT ON DOCUMENTTYPE
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE nombre_funcion();
```

Comment: Al eliminar el begin arroja:  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INSERT"
LINE 4: INSERT INTO AUD_DOCUMENTTYPE (

Comment: Ahora modifico la respuesta...

Comment: Listo ahi quedó

Comment: Quedó igualito a mi respuesta. Salvo que `:NEW` con los 2 puntos es también sintaxis de Oracle y no funciona en PostgreSQL.

Comment: No había visto que habías respondido. Recién lo veo. Fuiste más rapido que yo. No tengo el postgree acá para probar. Igual eso lo tiene que cambiar el OP. Son sus datos. Aunque es bueno el dato je

Comment: `:NEW` no tiene nada que ver con los datos. Es parte de la sintaxis de los triggers en Oracle.

Comment: Me refiero a que es lo que el OP escribió

Comment: Muchas Gracias Muchachos en Definitiva hay que crear la  función.

Comment: Así es. Cuando veo estas cosas más quiero a SQL Server.